# Wp8 Textbox keyup and keydown always Uppercase

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-8

In my wp8 app, i am using a textbox and at the keyup event i cam getting only the Uppercase even i press the lowercase button.
here is my code

```
 Private Sub MessageTextBoxKeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
   dim mys as string     
   mys = e.Key.ToString
 End Sub
```

How can i get lower and upper case.

Comment: KeyUp provides *virtual* keys, they have little to do with the text that's generated when you press the key.  Using the wrong event is common in WinRT, it is hard to find ,you need the CharacterReceived event.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `TextChanged` event to capture text change.

`KeyUp` event receives only single `Key` if you navigate to it you will see that there are no lower case letters.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, How can i get the Typed letter. I dont want the full text.